# Distance vector in a weighted graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I got a weighted, connected and directed graph $G$. There is a vector called the distance vector $Dv \in \mathbb{N}^n$ in which $Dv_i$ is the shortest distance from $1$ to $i$. All edge weights are positive integers. I have to show that every distance vector $Dv$ satisfies:

1. $Dv_1 = 0$.
2. For all $j \neq 1$ there exists $i$ such that $Dv_j = Dv_i + w(i,j)$.
3. For all $i,j$ it holds that $Dv_j \leq Dv_i + w(i,j)$.

I think that 1 is trivial: from 1 to 1 you have no distance. But the rest? Can you give me an idea how to prove 2 and 3?

Comment: try looking over the proof of the Djikstra Algorithm Essentially, what you are asking is  "why Djikstra works?"

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 2: If $1,\ldots,i,j$ is a shortest path from $1$ to $j$ then $1,\ldots,i$ is a shortest path from $1$ to $i$.

Hint for 3: If $1,\ldots,i$ is a path from $1$ to $i$ then $1,\ldots,i,j$ is a path from $1$ to $j$.

In both cases $\ldots$ represents some list of vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I think I have to show both directions because it is some sort of "if and only". To show the "=>" direction I just have to paint a grah 1->2->3 should be ok because all 3 terms are true. To 2. I think I got it with your help. If 1,...i,j is a shortest path than it has the same value as Dv_j and 1,...,i has to be the same as Dv_i. So that Dv_i -w(i,j) is equal to Dv_j. Is that right?

Comment: That's not what if and only if means in this context. It means that you have to show that if $Dv$ is a distance vector then it satisfies all three properties, and conversely, if $Dv$ satisfies all three properties then it is a distance vector.

Comment: For the "Dv satisfies all properties => it is a distance vector" direction, is it enough to show a single vektor which satisfies the properties and then show that it is the shortest?  And to make it more clear to me, what is Dv exactly ? I know that Dv_i is a shortest path form 1 to i but without an index I can not interpret Dv.

Comment: For the "Dv satisfies all properties => it is a distance vector" you need to show that if Dv is a vector satisfying the properties then Dv_i is the length of the shortest path from 1 to i. Here Dv is the vector whose i'th coordinate is Dv_i.

Comment: ok I think I got the "Dv is a distance vector then it satisifes all three properties" direction but can you give me a hint for the other one? I think it has to be so sort of "if a vector satisfys all properties and it is not the distance vetor then there has to be some sort of contradiction" thing.

Comment: Perhaps it's best if you first gave it a try. In real life there won't always be someone to give you hints all the time.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure about this, but if there is a vektor with this properties and it is not Distancevektor, than D_j don't has to be a shortest path form 1,..,j and it could be longer than D_i+w(i,j). But this is a contradiction to the 3. property. Is this right?